# Using a constructor within another constructor in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Finding trouble to understand the logic used in google earth engine. I am following a tutorial whereby the instructor used this code to filter from a collection of Landsat 8 images.

```
    var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 169))
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 58))
.filterDate('2021-05-01', '2021-08-30');

print('The collection: ', collection);

//conver the collection to a list and get no. of images
var size = collection.toList(100).length();
print('No. of images: ', size);

//get the no. of images
var count = collection.size();
print('Count: ', count);

//get the date range of images in the collection
var dates = ee.List(collection.get('date_range'));
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(dates.get(0), dates.get(1));
print(dateRange);

//sort by cloud cover property, get the least cloudy image
var image = ee.Image(collection.sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());
print('Least cloudy image: ', image);
```

Now, the big issues is that I would like to know when one can insert a constructor inside another constructor. For example, why did she insert `ee.Filter.eq` inside `ee.filter`? According to the `docs` tab of GEE, its true the `ee.filter` can accept another filter within the construct, but I initially thought the `ee.filter` could be competent enough to search for the Path/Row much like filtering dates. I was proved wrong on this since using `ee.filter('WRS_PATH', 169)` and `ee.filter('WRS_ROW', 58)` brought the following error:

`Line 1: Received too many arguments to function filter(). Expected at most 1 but got 2.`

A check for `ee.Filter.eq` shows that it is used to filter according to metadata. However, I would like to know when to use constructors within another constructor. I'm having problems understanding GEE javascript logic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing things up a bit.

`ee.filter` doesn't exist at all.

`ee.Filter()` is a generic filter constructor. It's something that I typically don't use, but it's good to know that it's there. According to the docs:

> Constructs a new filter. This constructor accepts the following args:
>
> - Another filter.
> - A list of filters (which are implicitly ANDed together).
> - A `ComputedObject` returning a filter. Users shouldn't be making these; they're produced by the generator functions below.

`filter()` is a method on `ee.ImageCollection` (and `ee.FeatureCollection`). It takes a single argument, the filter you want to apply to the image collection. According to the docs:

> Apply a filter to this collection. Returns the filtered collection.

Then you have all the `ee.Filter.*()` functions, like `ee.Filter.eq()`. They constructs different types of filters. You apply them to a collection by passing them to the `ee.ImageCollection.filter()` method mentioned above.

In addition to this, `ee.ImageCollection` have a number of "shortcut" methods that sometimes save you some typing for common types of filters. These two operations filters the collection the same way:

```
collection.filterDate('2021-05-01', '2021-08-30')
collection.filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-05-01', '2021-08-30'))
```

This is another example:

```
collection.filterMetadata('WRS_PATH', 'equals', 169)
collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 169))
```